# catch exception in its initializer object

Tags: javascript, exception

I have an Ajax object which is used in some other objects to load 'Json' files.

I need to catch the 404 'Not found' thrown exception in the initializer object, but I couldn't do this it always gives me:

> Uncaught Exception : *********

here a piece of code:

```
_ajax_params.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (_ajax_params.xmlhttp.readyState==4 && _ajax_params.xmlhttp.status==200) {
        _ajax_params.response = _ajax_params.xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (typeof afterClosure == 'function') {
            afterClosure(_ajax_params.response);
        }
        COMMON.always(_ajax_params.response);
    } else if (_ajax_params.xmlhttp.status== 404) {
        throw 'File not found';
    }
};
```

In the initializer object:

```
try {
   Base.include.json(url, 1);
} catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
   Base.include.json(url,2);
}
```

I tried to re-throw exception, but I got the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may have *defined* the callback within a `try..catch` block, but the function is *executed* outside of said block (ie. when the event is fired). This means that exceptions that happen in the callback will not be caught by the outside block.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/39EQH/) is a demonstration of the difference in action.

Consider calling `Base.include.json(url,2)` in place of `throw 'File not found';`

Additionally, you shouldn't really check `status` unless you already know that `readyState` is `4`, but that's a minor thing.

Comment: Consider calling Base.include.json(url,2) in place of throw 'File not found';

Maybe I cannot do this , because Base.include.json is a general object, so it is used it many different places.

Comment: I removed throw statement, I kept getting an exception 404. that's good, but I need to handle that exception in the initializer object.
I'm still trying

Comment: How about replacing the `throw` with `callErrorHandlerFunction`, a function that you define in your initializer object?

Comment: That seems good but I may cannot do it because of the reason I have mentioned in my previous comment.